# How to get rid from the Content Security Policy directive issue?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my project I have made my connections runs over https. but I don't know why the following issue arises?

```
[Report Only] Refused to load the image 'https://domain:3000/assets/loading.gif' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src data:".
```

home:1

Answer (score 0):

Check out point Nr.3 at http://people.mozilla.org/~bsterne/content-security-policy/details.html.

It seems like you will have to send your pages with a header containing `X-Content-Security-Policy: allow 'self'; img-src data:`. That should do the job.

Comment: Yeah, that i understand. how to set that header? can you please tell me that?

Comment: That depends on what you're using as a server.

Comment: I'm using thin web server

Comment: http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/usage/ 
It's setting headers there right in the first example.

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme are you sure you have the correct link there?  That doesn't seem at all relevant...

Answer (score 0):

You have (your web browser has) a "Content Security Policy" which restricts the source of images to "data".  That is, like this:

```
src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwALAIAAAAAA3pn/ZiH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAALAAsAAAIUhA+hkcuO4lmNVindo7qyrIXiGBYAOw=='
```

If you want to load images from 'domain' you will need to adjust your CSP to allow this.  More info on CSP here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP